# why left join on clause doesn't work

Tags: t-sql

[please look this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zqLYZ.png)

the first query does not retrieve any row that MemberType > 4,
all MemberType just <=4.

But the second query, there is a MemberType = 5 , it seems the on clause does not work. i don't get it. if you can give me a cue, i'll appreciate it.

Comment: LEFT join returns all rows for the first table,its just the condition will return NULL if they dont have a match in the second table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no WHERE clause in the second query, so you get all rows from table `member`.

Then you outer-join table `daili` with the following condition: when member.membertype <=4 and matching account records are found in `daili` then join these, otherwise just keep the `member` record with an empty `daili` record.

So for a membertype > 4 you always outer-join an empty `daili` record.

Remove `membertype <= 4` from your ON clause, because you don't want it to be a join condition. Put in in the WHERE clause instead, because you want to limit your result set.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put MemberType <= 4 in WHERE clause instead of having it in part of the left join.